# Is it possible to pass a valueless input attribute to a component?

Tags: angular

An html element can be passed a valueless attribute that *implies* a value, such as `required` to an `input` element. Is possible to do the same thing with an angular component?

An example:

```
<my-component required></my-component>

...

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() required;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.required); // true??
  }
}
```

Comment: Plz add more detail to your question jcroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular doesn't provide direct support, but there are workarounds

```
  isRequired:boolean = false;
  @Input() set required(val) {
    this.isRequired = true; // only called when the attribute exists
  }
```

or

```
  constructor(@Attribute('required') required) {
    console.log('constructor': required == '');
  }
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/UpbcJE0JOKlsCSAbicad?p=preview)

I haven't tested how it behaves when the attribute is dynamically added/removed.

Answer (score 0):

A valueless attribute comes in as an empty string. If you need to support the attribute in both valued and valueless forms, define the setter as follows:

```
@Input() set required(val: (boolean | string)) {
    if (typeof val === 'boolean') {
        this.isRequired = val;
    } else {
        this.isRequired = value.length === 0 || value === 'true';
    }
}
```

This works with an attribute binding (`[required]="..."`) as well.